# Can I override the session provider for a specific page?

Tags: asp.net, session-state, sql-session-state

Can I specify, say the InProc Session Provider for one page, and a database backed session provider for all other pages?

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: I'd like my application to store session in a database, e.g. oracle or sql. But that requires that everything that is put into session to be serializable. However, there are some 3rd party components, (Crystal report viewers) that put nonserializable data into Session. In the past I've had to create a 2nd asp.net app & vdir to host just the pages that had the components that require inproc session-- that creates a ugly integration projects trying to make two applications behave as one (with one auth prompt, seamless navigation when ~/ isn't enough to find all pages, etc)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can. Please check the following article out: http://abhijitjana.net/2011/01/15/programmatically-changing-session-state-behavior-in-asp-net-4-0/

Comment: That example uses currentContext.SetSessionStateBehavior(System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateBehavior.ReadOnly); to change the session among: disabled, required, read-only or default, but it doesn't seem to allow changing any other characteristics of session.